# How do I load files in an html page, after being transferred to a different computer?

Tags: html, image, path

When I send a zipped filed of my website over to my other computer, the link appears to be broken. Is there a way to somehow embed the images to the folder and not to my harddrive?

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="file:///Users/Platyous/Desktop/Summer%202016dt/DIg2500/Semester%20Website%20-%20Gintama%20Fan%20page/Images/Gintoki.png">Sakata Gintoki</li>
    <li>
      <img src="file:///Users/Platyous/Desktop/Summer%202016dt/DIg2500/Semester%20Website%20-%20Gintama%20Fan%20page/Images/Kagura.jpg">Kagura</li>
    <li>
      <img src="file:///Users/Platyous/Desktop/Summer%202016dt/DIg2500/Semester%20Website%20-%20Gintama%20Fan%20page/Images/Shinpachi.jpg">Shimura Shinpachi</li>
  </ul>
```

The same also goes for my navigation.

```
  <nav>
    <a href="file:///Users/Platyous/Desktop/Summer%202016dt/DIg2500/Semester%20Website%20-%20Gintama%20Fan%20page/home.html">Home</a> |
    <a href="file:///Users/Platyous/Desktop/Summer%202016dt/DIg2500/Semester%20Website%20-%20Gintama%20Fan%20page/Gintama.html">Gintama The Show</a> |
    <a href="file:///Users/Platyous/Desktop/Summer%202016dt/DIg2500/Semester%20Website%20-%20Gintama%20Fan%20page/Games.html">Games</a> 
  </nav>
```

Comment: Do a google search on relative paths. This way your paths will be relative to your application and not absolute.

Comment: Why don't you use relative paths instead of global ones?

Comment: I didn't know the correct term for what I was looking for. I tried google and it didn't work but now I know. Thank you ^^

Answer (score -1):

As the comments suggest, [using relative paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html#h-5.1.2) will solve this issue.

If you're only using this website for the purpose of opening your HTML files in the browser without the intent of ever hosting them on a server then the following will work:

```
Images/Gintoki.png
home.html
```

However, the below suggestion is targeted towards event where this markup is reused and is loaded relative to the domain (hosted on a website or loaded through a local web server). In that case, use a URI relative path:

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="/Images/Gintoki.png">Sakata Gintoki</li>
  <li><img src="/Images/Kagura.jpg">Kagura</li>
  <li><img src="/Images/Shinpachi.jpg">Shimura Shinpachi</li>
</ul>

<nav>
  <a href="/home.html">Home</a> |
  <a href="/Gintama.html">Gintama The Show</a> |
  <a href="/Games.html">Games</a> 
</nav>
```

Doing this allows nested directory/paths to load the files relative to the directory they're being served from and not the path that it's being requested from. It's usually best to test your website as it would be if you were hosting it live.

Launching a static web server in the root of the website, from terminal, such as `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` is a great way to ensure everything will work live.

An explanation for the issue you're seeing is simply that your other computer hosts the files in a different directory, probably something like so:

```
file:///Users/MyOtherComputer/Desktop/Summer%202016dt/DIg2500/Semester%20Website%20-%20Gintama%20Fan%20page/home.html
```

As a result of the images pointing to a path absolute to your other computer, the browser is requesting the image from the original destination and due to it not being there, a [404 (Not Found)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) is being returned.

Comment: `/Images/Gintoki.png` is absolute path, `Images/Gintoki.png` is relative.

Comment: Notice the keywords relative to the domain. In fact... this is the de-facto way to refer to files which are hosted relative to the HTML documents. Please don't down vote because I rejected your suggested change. Please download https://github.com/sethkrasnianski/forwardslash-prefixed-relative-urls, run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` then go to http://localhost:8000/my-directory/test.html and you'll notice a forward-slash prefixed image src.

Comment: @vsakos You might find this [W3C training on hyperlinks](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Training/Hyper_Links#Relative_paths_or_Absolute_URL) useful or this [Wikipedia article on Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Examples_of_absolute_URIs)

Comment: @Seth I think you're wrong. Slash prefixed URLs are relative to the _root_, not the _current directory_, so actually they're absolute paths. Try putting all of those files in the git repo to an another folder and you will see. It works for you because you're accessing it relative to the _root_ of the web server. But if he is using `/Images/Gintoki.png`, that will actually be `file:///Images/Gintoki.png` and not  `file:///an/absolute/path/Images/Gintoki.png`

Comment: In the context of directly viewing html pages from the file system, you're correct. However html pages are meant for web servers. Anyone will find this practice immensely useful if they intend to have websites with nested paths.